# Lambda Function using ssm.send_command from boto3 library- getting error "datetime.datetimeis not JSON serializable"

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, datetime, boto3

Using this code:

```
command = ssm.send_command( InstanceIds=[ 'i-xxxxxxxxxx' ], DocumentName='AWS-RunPowerShellScript', Comment='Restarting Server', Parameters={ "commands":[".\\python.exe C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\script.py"], "workingDirectory": ["C:\\Python36"] } )
return command
```

I am receiving this error in my AWS Lambda function:

```
An error occurred during JSON serialization of response: datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 16, 0, 16, 2, 314000, tzinfo=tzlocal()) is not JSON serializable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/var/runtime/awslambda/bootstrap.py", line 110, in decimal_serializer
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 16, 0, 16, 2, 314000, tzinfo=tzlocal()) is not JSON serializable
```

This doesn't make any sense to me because I'm not using any method that has to do with datetime.datetime.
That command variable I guess has JSON in it but I'm not sure why it appears to be using datetime.

Comment: What's script.py doing?

Comment: It's sending API commands to my monitoring application, Centreon.

Comment: This looks like an issue with Boto3 send_command API. It's unable to serialize the response of the API request. Open an issue on the [project repository](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/808) after you confirm one doesn't exist for it. You may want to patch `json.encode` to handle serialization of datetime objects for the time being.

Comment: Did you get a resolution to this issue? I have the same issue when trying to return back the result of an s3.Object.copy_from() function.

Comment: @belial yes, I did.  AWS doesn't have any library for time, so Just add "import time" to the top of your code.  Once I added that it worked.